# Document is not being saved in database

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

In Article model, I want to save a list of categories:

```
var CategorySchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  active: Boolean
});

var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: String,
  description: String,
  categories: [{ type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' }]
})
```

From the endpoint, I want to update article with categories. The update method looks like:

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
  Article.findById(req.params.id, function (err, article) {
    if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    if(!article) { return res.send(404); }
    var updated = _.merge(article, req.body);

    updated.save(function (err, doc) {
      console.log(doc);
      if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
      return res.json(200, article);
    });
  });
};
```

Notice the `console.log` statement. In `request.body`, if I'm sending list of category ids, the console prints out an article with categories. However, when I look into the database, the category array is empty. Any pointer to how to solve this?

Comment: See [`.findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) and [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/). Apart from other inherrent problems in what you are doing, and understanding of those pages should explain clearly how to do it correctly and safely.

Comment: If you do `findByIdAndUpdate` the model does not go through any validation. Could you clarify what are the problems with the way it is now? Any idea why is it not working?

Comment: Yes it will not go through any schema validation unless you build in the smarts to do so, It also will not "overwrite" the data committed from any other transaction that occurred in between your `.findById()` and `.save()` operations. So "not safe". Anyhow a mongoose object is not a "plain object" and cannot be basically "merged" without converting it to a raw object anyhow. See .`toObject()`.